# Center tag not working properly

Tags: html, css, web

I had my frame design and I wanted to experiment inside the #content div now. I wanted to center a text, but it is not working properly.

It can be seen on my page.

The most important parts (after removal of script and other link tags) of index.HTML can be seen here:

```css
body {
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  background-color: #dfc;
  color: #000;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #5dbf61;
  z-index: 100;
}

.stickyTop {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}

.stickySidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.sidebar>.option {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.option:hover {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

.sidebar>.selected {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.panel {
  width: 226px;
  /*250 - 12 - 12*/
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar>.empty {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.empty-border {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  left: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9b8;
  background-color: #bda;
  color: #796;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.stickyNavbar {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #796;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 250px;
  top: 76px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.spaced-text {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.fixed-center {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><b>Nieposortowane</b></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></div>
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Przyklad 1</a></div>
    <div class="selected"><a href="#">Może coś tu będzie</a></div>
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Strona Niegłówna</a></div>
    <div class="empty-border"></div>
    <div class="panel" id="info">
      <b class="spaced-text">Informacje o stronie</b><br/><br/> Ta strona jeszcze nie jest stroną, bo trwa robienie designu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet jakoś tak cośtam dalej nie pamiętam a nie chce mi się kopiować.
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="style-switcher">
      <b class="spaced-text">Wybieranie stylu strony</b><br /><br />
      <b>Styl strony:</b><br />
      <input type="radio" id="style_1" name="design" onclick="update();" checked>Normalny</input><br />
      <input type="radio" id="style_2" name="design" onclick="update();">Dark</input><br />
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="footer">
      <b>Nieposortowane.pl &copy; 2017<br />
        Karol Turbiarz</b><br /><br /> Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone<br /> All rights reserved
    </div>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Nieposortowane.pl</a> > <a href="#">Strona główna</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <center>a</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see how the center is off much to the right. How can it be fixed?

Comment: The text is centered within the div properly - the issue is that the `content` div that it's centered in is much wider than the page itself. Additionally, drop the `<center>` altogether and just put `text-align: center;` on the `content` div.

Comment: `<center/>` is a deprecated html element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. Use css to center text.

Comment: @LuudJacobs when I do it with css, the same thing happens

Comment: Again, your `content` div is much larger than the page. You may need to use some variation of `vw` and `calc()` to achieve the proper value. Try `width: calc(100vw - 250px)` on the `content` div.

Comment: @KKZiomek no reason to resort to `<center/>`. Check the comment @Santi dropped

Comment: @Santi I don't want to have everything centered though, only the text I want to be centered.

Comment: Your markup is a mess. Why is everything `position:fixed`? Your content has 100% width (of the parent container), but is shifted 250px to the right. There are tons of articles out there, how to build a modern website, even [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_website.asp) has pretty high quality material nowadays.

Comment: @Christoph I'm not an advanced designer, it's just my home page with amateur design after 3 hours of learning css.

Comment: @Santi calc doesn't work, is there another way?

Comment: *"not working properly"* is not a problem description, please write exactly what the problem is, without vague words

Comment: @LuudJacobs Worse than that, `<center>` is obsolete: https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: Wow, where the 4 downvotes came from?

Comment: @KKZiomek You are using obsolete methods. Also, read the comments.

Comment: @Rob I read the comments, but the tutorial I learned html had center and all the now-obsolete tags in it. It is unfair to downvote because I didn't even know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Issues:**

**1.** `<center>` is *[obsolete](https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete)*, so we'll use CSS instead (`text-align: center;` on the parent element will work the same as `<center>`)

**2.** Your text is properly centered within the `content` div, the issue is that the `content` div is much too wide. You have it set to `width: 100%`, but because it is `position: fixed;` that 100% means *100% of the **page***. That's 250px too much, because it isn't compensating for the side-bar.

---

**A piece of personal advice:**

Truthfully, this page is a mess. You have nearly no elements *"in-the-flow"* because nothing is relatively positioned. Fixing the issue you've pointed out is sort of like building a house on top of quicksand, and then asking how to fix the dripping pipe in your kitchen.

The less `position: absolute;` and `position: fixed;` elements you can use, the better off you'll be when it comes to general page structure. In some cases absolute-positioning might be exactly what you need, but most of the time you want the page to *flow*. The items should be properly nested within one another, and they should position and align themselves without relying on hard-coded positional attributes.

Down the line, some common, modern techniques include [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), though I personally have always been an advocate of learning the basics beforehand.

[Support table and Resources for **Grid layout**](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid%20layout)
[Support table and Resources for **Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

---

**Despite that, if you're really in a pinch, here's a quick solution:**

Change your `content` div to be `100%` of the width of the page, *but compensate for the 250px sidebar*, by using `calc(100% - 250px)`.

Additionally, `border` and `padding` are *additive* by default, meaning `20px` of total padding and a width of `500px` results in a `520px` true-width. We can avoid this behavior by implementing `box-sizing: border-box`, which applies padding and borders *inward* instead of *outward*.

```
.content {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I am sitting in the corner weeping about the code, but your solution is correct. Please mention grid layout in your answer to make me less sad. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Christoph I considered it, but I feel like knowing `relative` vs `absolute` and "CSS flow" should probably be engraved in your mind before you start working with techniques like flexbox or grid. That being said, I've edited my answer to note them!

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix your center problem, add `text-align: center;` to the parent will center the child element inside), `<center>` tag are not supported anymore for HTML5 so you should not use it.

also use `width: calc(100% - 250px);` for the content since your left menu have a width of 250px;

```css
body {
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  background-color: #dfc;
  color: #000;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #5dbf61;
  z-index: 100;
}

.stickyTop {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
}

.stickySidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.sidebar>.option {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.option:hover {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

.sidebar>.selected {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.panel {
  width: 226px;
  /*250 - 12 - 12*/
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebar>.empty {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.sidebar>.empty-border {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 12px;
  color: #dfc;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  left: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9b8;
  background-color: #bda;
  color: #796;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.stickyNavbar {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #796;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 100%;
  left: 250px;
  top: 76px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.spaced-text {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.fixed-center {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><b>Nieposortowane</b></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></div>
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Przyklad 1</a></div>
    <div class="selected"><a href="#">Może coś tu będzie</a></div>
    <div class="option"><a href="#">Strona Niegłówna</a></div>
    <div class="empty-border"></div>
    <div class="panel" id="info">
      <b class="spaced-text">Informacje o stronie</b><br/><br/> Ta strona jeszcze nie jest stroną, bo trwa robienie designu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet jakoś tak cośtam dalej nie pamiętam a nie chce mi się kopiować.
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="style-switcher">
      <b class="spaced-text">Wybieranie stylu strony</b><br /><br />
      <b>Styl strony:</b><br />
      <input type="radio" id="style_1" name="design" onclick="update();" checked>Normalny</input><br />
      <input type="radio" id="style_2" name="design" onclick="update();">Dark</input><br />
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="footer">
      <b>Nieposortowane.pl &copy; 2017<br />
        Karol Turbiarz</b><br /><br /> Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone<br /> All rights reserved
    </div>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Nieposortowane.pl</a> > <a href="#">Strona główna</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>abc</span>
  </div>
</div>
```